# object properties visable in function1 but not function2

Tags: php

I am learning php objects but I am confused by the results of this code. When the `mail` function is called, all of the object properties are passed as expected and there are no errors. When the `MakeCommuni` function is called, the first three properties are passed but the last two, which are the same object properties as the previous function, produce the following error:

**Notice: Undefined property: obj_em_OrPS::$getToAdd in .../public_html/i_sendEmail.php on line 45**

```
$objASstr = file_get_contents($usFile);
$objEM = unserialize($objASstr);
$mResult = 'Uh-Oh... test test.';
if (mail($objEM->getToAdd(),$objEM->getSubject(),$objEM->getBody(),$objEM->getHeader())){
    $mResult = 'eMail has been sent.';
    $mResul2 = MakeCommuni($mOrderID, date("Y-m-d H:m:s"), 'email',$objEM->getToAdd,$objEM->getSubject);
}
else {
    $mResult = 'Uh-Oh... NO! NO! eMail has NOT been sent.';
}
```

(BTW MakeCommuni() is a custom function that runs w/o error elsewhere)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're missing the parentheses in your funcion calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses in your function calls, so PHP assumes an object property is being called:

```
$mResul2 = MakeCommuni($mOrderID, date("Y-m-d H:m:s"), 'email',$objEM->getToAdd,$objEM->getSubject);
```

Should be:

```
$mResul2 = MakeCommuni($mOrderID, date("Y-m-d H:m:s"), 'email',$objEM->getToAdd(), $objEM->getSubject());
```

Comment: Thank you Niche. It is not the first time I have made that mistake.